# Object reference not set to an instance - error on server after update/restart

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I'm hoping you can help me. I'm getting the Object reference error on a webserver which contains an application we run.

Someone reset it this week and updated the server with (about) 50 new updates. I know. terrible. Anyway.. since then we're getting this error.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 36:         Hashtable items = mc.LanguageController.GetLanguageItems(ClientConfiguration.Language, languageItems);
>
> Line 37:         XmlElement itemsElem = doc.CreateElement("Lang");
>
> Line 38:         doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(itemsElem);
>
> Source File: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\xxxxxxxx\www\App_Code\Rendering\Rendering.cs    Line: 36
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
>
> Rendering.GetRootDocument(String[] languageItems, IMainController mc) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\xxxxxxxxxxxx\www\App_Code\Rendering\Rendering.cs:36
>
> Rendering.GetDefaultDocument(IMainController mc) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\xxxxxxxxxxxx\www\App_Code\Rendering\Rendering.cs:53
>
> _Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\xxxxxxxxxxxx\www\Default.aspx.cs:31
>
> System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
>
> System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
>
> System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
>
> System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
>
> System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean  includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4216; ASP.NET  Version:2.0.50727.4223

I've checked the Event log as well:

> Event code: 3005
>
> Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred.
>
> Event time: 29-3-2012 12:47:38
>
> Event time (UTC): 29-3-2012 10:47:38
>
> Event ID: 69890cf8cf244b18a5adcbd29ae9a189
>
> Event sequence: 25
>
> Event occurrence: 8
>
> Event detail code: 0
>
> Application information:
>
> Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-3-129774906346518390
>
> Trust level: Full
>
> Application Virtual Path: /
>
> Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\xxxxxxxx\www\
>
> Machine name: WIN-PKNHIWTOENT
>
> Process information:
>
> Process ID: 4288
>
> Process name: w3wp.exe
>
> Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
>
> Exception information:
>
> Exception type: NullReferenceException
>
> Exception message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Request information:
>
> Request URL: http://xxxxxxxx/default.aspx
>
> Request path: /default.aspx
>
> User host address: yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
>
> User:
>
> Is authenticated: False
>
> Authentication Type:
>
> Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
>
> Thread information:
>
> Thread ID: 8
>
> Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
>
> Is impersonating: False
>
> Stack trace:    at Rendering.GetRootDocument(String[] languageItems, IMainController 
>   mc) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\xxxxxxxxxxxx\www\App_Code\Rendering\Rendering.cs:line 36
>
> at Rendering.GetDefaultDocument(IMainController mc) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\xxxxxxxxxxxx\www\App_Code\Rendering\Rendering.cs:line 53
>
> at _Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\xxxxxxxxxxxx\www\Default.aspx.cs:line 31
>
> at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, 
>   EventArgs e)
>
> at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>
> at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
>
> at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
>
> at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean 
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

I suspect it's the languageItems variable, which is being passed from another function:

> public static XmlDocument GetOverviewDocument(IMainController mc) {
>
> ```
>    string[] languageItems = { 
>
>       "usermanagement", 
>
>       "customermanagement", 
>
>       "ordermanagement", 
>
>       "ordermanagement LB", 
>
>       "systemmanagement",
>
>       "qualitymanagement",
>
>       "overview",
>
>       "loggedinas",
>
>       "logout",
>
>       "Change password",
>
>       "managementoverview"
>
>   };
>
>  XmlDocument doc = GetRootDocument(languageItems, mc);
>
>  return doc;
> ```
>
> }

Since I'm not an ASP guru like most of you I have no idea what's actually happening here; whether it's something to do with the updates to .NET which were installed, if it's code-syntax related or if there's a simple config mistake in web.config which I'm overlooking.

Any help would be most, MOST appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

o, so:
`Line 36: Hashtable items = mc.LanguageController.GetLanguageItems(ClientConfiguration.Language, languageItems);`

Are sure that it's `languageitems` variable? 
Because I'm starting to think that `mc` could `null`  or `ClientConfiguration`(if it's property).

Comment: Not really.. no. My knowledge of ASP ends where the code above ends: it's the first time I've seriously had a look at it. ClientConfiguration.Language could be the culprit, I guess.. I wouldn't know where to look for it or if it's a standard library being used or some sort of hacked-off library made in the early to mid 2000s when this application went live.

Comment: My gues was that `ClientConfiguratin.Language` could throw `NullReferenceException` because `ClientConfiguration` is `null`. I'm not ASP professional, but seems like `ClientConfiguration` is not built-in ASP class, so If you can open source in VisualStudio then try to find out what is that `ClientConfiguration` by invoking Visual Studio's 'Go To Declaration' or 'Go To Definition' context menu command for `ClientConfiguration` token. Pls, let us know the result, thanks.